# Faster mobile site than desktop

Tags: mobile, seo, desktop, pagespeed

Google and other search engines have speed as a ranking factor. They think mobile sites should load below [1 second](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-page-speed-mobile-17202.html).

**Different speed, mobile and desktop**

Is there a good method to load the site with different speed? I can check with PHP what device that are used but nowdays sites are responsive with CSS.

**Mobile site with speed**

What is the "correct" way to make the mobile site much faster than the desktop version? How do I load the images differently when the site is responsive via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look on **[Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)** on *website performance best practices and rules*..

(taken from Yslow):

- Minimize HTTP Requests
- Use a Content Delivery Network
- Avoid empty src or href
- Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
- Gzip Components
- Put StyleSheets at the Top
- Put Scripts at the Bottom
- Avoid CSS Expressions
- Make JavaScript and CSS External
- Reduce DNS Lookups
- Minify JavaScript and CSS
- Avoid Redirects
- Remove Duplicate Scripts
- Configure ETags
- Make AJAX Cacheable
- Use GET for AJAX Requests
- Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
- No 404s
- Reduce Cookie Size
- Use Cookie-Free Domains for Components
- Avoid Filters
- Do Not Scale Images in HTML
- Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable

If you follow these already and still get a load time > 1s *(you can check using [this](http://www.webpagetest.org/))*, you can look further on
**Responsive Images**,
there is a good read on that **[here](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/)**,
 which basically means depending on the width of the browser you serve different sizes of images, which makes sense because for example why would you serve a '3000px' image on a '320px' mobile browser?

How, you say? One simple example is by using [User Agent strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to determine if it is from a mobile/tablet device.. and serve the appropriate size of images depending on it. *Take note however that UA strings are not 100% accurate and can be spoofed.*

** If you happen to be using PHP, there is this library called **[mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net/)** that might help you..
** If you want to detect if the user is using 3G/2G, **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885402/is-there-a-way-to-detect-3g-and-2g-connections-speed-on-mobile-phones-and-handhe)** might help..